# Wowza recording rtmp stream to S3

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I am on a Amazon AWS instance which has Wowza Media Server installed. I am trying to record streaming videos to an S3 bucket. Basically trying to follow [this](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?72-S3FS-Fuse-based-file-system) tutorial.

I've mounted the bucket (2 of them) so when I run `df -h` command I get

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            9.9G  1.3G  8.1G  14% /
tmpfs                 3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb             414G  237M  393G   1% /media/ephemeral0
s3fs                  256T     0  256T   0% /mnt/s3
s3fs                  256T     0  256T   0% /mnt/s3-1
```

next I edited this file `/usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/conf/live/Application.xml` because I assume I want to record live streams. I added the `<Module>` and `<Property>` information in there according to the tutorial above.

But when I stream live from Adobe Flash Media Encoder no video is saved in the S3 bucket. Can anyone point me when I am doing wrong or if I missed a step here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer: got to set `<StreamType>` to `live-record` in place of `live` in the config Application.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

Change `<StreamType>` from `live` to `live-record` in the Application XML

Or:

From the engine manager console, go to Applications > Live > Edit (blue button) and turn on the checkbox option "Record all incoming streams".

These two change the same configuration value.

Comment: Is the engine manager a recent addition? Because the question is from 2012 :)